# WordPress comments on users profile

Tags: comments, author, profiles

I have a profile page and I need to make a comment system on it. The comments system should work exactly the same way as standard WordPress comment system, but instead of posts it should work with users. For better understanding, I have 1 page which acts as a profile for every user (user_login is in the URL) and at the bottom of that page users can leave comments about ‘profile’ user.

Any ideas how to achieve this? What should be changed? Is there any wordpress plugin for this of can you send me any PHP function for this.

Comment: You can store the comments as user meta for that particular user. But there won't be nested comments as the default comment system.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do accomplish something similar with an old client where they wanted a custom comment type to allow them to post editorial comments in the admin while a post is going through the editorial phase, but should not be visible on the front end.  Since there are no custom comment types available in WordPress we decided to create a hidden post type that would then be related back to the other post type or in your case, the user.  This way you can still have nested comments with no issue.